# How to solve uncaught typeerror: cannot read property 'getDisplayList' of null

Tags: reactjs, typescript, charts, echarts

seeing the same error as: https://segmentfault.com/q/1010000022589791

Error occurs when I use the the `onEvents` argument of Echarts to call on an external function. How do I get around it?

```
interface ParamsInterface {
    type: "datazoom";
    start: number;
    end: number;
}

interface TimeRange {
    start: number;
    end: number;
}

const [time, setTime] = useState<TimeRange>({start: 0, end: 100});

const onEvents = useMemo(
    () => ({
        dataZoom: (params: ParamsInterface) => {
            const newTime: TimeRange = {
                start: params.start,
                end: params.end,
            }
            setTime(newTime);
        }
    }), []
}

return <Echarts option={option} onEvents={onEvents} />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using echarts-for-react.

Based on [this](https://github.com/hustcc/echarts-for-react/issues/366) discussion, you should avoid calling `setState` directly from the `onEvents` handler. Instead define the handler externally and wrap it with `useCallback`:

```
const onDataZoom = useCallback((params: ParamsInterface) => {
        const newTime: TimeRange = {
            start: params.start,
            end: params.end,
        }
        setTime(newTime);
    }, []);

const onEvents = {
    dataZoom: onDataZoom
}
```

Comment: thank you! I tried it out and it works. I've also just updated the question to include a possibility of using `useMemo` as well (that was something I tried first before seeing your answer - though I think your answer makes more sense with the `useCallback` ).